# How can I draw a logic circuit of function F = (A+BCD)(A'+B'C'D') using 3 Xor gate and 1 AND gate?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, circuit

i want to simplify the function first but

i have no idea how to do it. already tried few ways but failed.

I think i have to use dmorgan's law or x xor y = x'y + y'x or something more..

can anyone help?

Comment: This is off-topic - suggest reading through  [What questions can I ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

Try a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to minimize the term. You can find further methods to minimize such terms in this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization_for_Boolean_functions).